# Get value of page in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Does anyone know a way to get the value of the page that the user is on in Datatables? I'm trying to keep the page during a reload, but fnStandingRedraw and bStateSave aren't working for me, so I'm trying it manually.

Basically, I want to be able to store the variable, and then restore the user to that page. Problem is, I can't figure out to get the variable in the first place.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `bStateSave` should work - are you getting any errors in the console? What's your datasource?

Comment: No errors in the console. I believe it's JSON/ajax/server-side.

Comment: It's been driving me crazy for days!

Comment: Try inspecting the request to make sure the page var is being passed to the server

Comment: How can I do that? I'm using chrome dev tools, and cant seem to put a stopper on the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to get around this.

If you utilize fnPagingInfo (http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnPagingInfo), it will send you the value of the page number.

Afterward, to send them to that page, just use fnPageChange and pass it the integer value you want (pages are 0 based in Datatables), and you should be well on your way. Also, this won't put any cookies in your browser!

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

In new API it is simple:

```
table.page();
```

Look here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page%28%29

Answer (score 0):

### ***fnDraw(false)***

is better than getting and setting page number.